# What is the difference between `type()` `__class__` and `__bases__` in Python?

Tags: python, oop, types

I tried this in Python's REPL:

```
>>> class Foo:
...  def f():{}
... 
>>> 
>>> type(Foo)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> Foo.__bases__
()
>>> type(type(Foo))
<type 'type'>
>>> type(Foo).__bases__
(<type 'object'>,)
```

However, I still can't figure out what "data type" means in OOP exactly.

In Python, I know that an instance can get its class by `.__class__` and a class can get its parent class by `.__bases__`.  This seems easy to understand.

But what does the the `type` of a "Class", or `TypeObject`, mean? And what does the `type` of a `Type Object` mean? What does the `__bases__` of a `Type Object` mean? What is the difference between `type` and `class` in Python?

This looks a bit confusing to me.. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Your code is tagged `python-3.x` but it looks like `python-2.x` - `type(Foo)` returns `<type 'type'>`  in python 3+.

Comment: This is not directly related to this question, but good to know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding is recognizing that everything in python is an object.  Also, technically `object` isn't a keyword, it's a global built-in.

[This answer is perhaps the best explanation I've ever seen on the topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/1547004)  I highly recommend reading the entire post.  It talks a lot about metaclasses, and `type` is very much tied to metaclasses.

Essentially, the type of a Class is a MetaClass.  And in the same way that all new-style classes in python inherit from `object`, all metaclasses inherit from `type`.  It's a bit confusing because the `type` global in python is used for two different purposes.  It's a metaclass and a function that returns the type of an object.

A very simple way to think of it is that metaclasses create classes, in the same way that Classes create instances.

Answer (score 0):

In python classes are objects, ie classes are 'something which is like anything else'
In your example,

```
class Foo():
    pass

x = Foo()

type(x)                     # Foo, x is a Foo
type(Foo)                   # type, Foo is a type
```

Foo ie a class you defined is not just a piece of code.  It is an object which takes space in memory.

```
Foo == 1                    # Valid comparisson which evaluates to False
Bar = Foo                   # Assign new variable bar as Foo
```

Are valid operations.

```
>>> type(type(Foo))
<type 'type'>
```

type is a special kind of class ([metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/3857234))
and it's objects are classes which can create objects